# MySQL: "Found option without preceding group in config file"

Tags: apache2, mysql, dropbox

I have a Windows machine on which I've moved the WAMP www and MySQL data directories to Dropbox.

Those Dropbox folders have downloaded to my Ubuntu laptop.

I'd like to run the websites in /home/me/Dropbox/WAMP/WWW on my Ubuntu laptop using the MySQL data in /home/me/Dropbox/WAMP/SQL/Data.

I've edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
datadir=/home/me/Dropbox/WAMP/SQL/Data
```

I've edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "\home\me\Dropbox\WAMP\WWW\site"
    ServerName www.site.dev
    ServerAlias www.site.dev
    <Directory "\home\me\Dropbox\WAMP\WWW\site">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've edited `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 www.site.dev
```

I've restarted apache2, and when I run `www.site.dev` in my browser, I am taken to the default apache2 index.html.

When I run >mysql start, I receive:

```
mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23!
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

Line 23 of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is:

```
datadir=/home/me/Dropbox/WAMP/SQL/Data
```

Help appreciated.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020319/667903), I've opened `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in Sublime Text editor, and saved it as UT-8 (without BOM), and the issue remains.

Comment: What is *above* line 23?  If you added this line above the first line with a group identifier (which is enclosed in `[` `]`, such as `[mysqld]`) then the error is telling you exactly what is wrong -- you've added the entry in the wrong place in the file.